# Can I simplify this using recursion?

Tags: java

Not sure If i can simplify the two for loops as they are similar? Any help appreciated. Can I use recursion?

```
public static Integer Search(int array[])
{   
    //Loop through original array 
    for(int compare : array)
    {
        int count = 0;

        //Will loop through array and compare each integer to compare
        for(int currentInt : array)
        {
            //Comparing currentInt to compare
            if (currentInt == compare)
                count += 1;

            //If the currentInt is in the array twice
            if (count == 2)
                return currentInt;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if recursion would be your best bet here. Yes, you CAN use recursion, but try to think if that would actually help you solve the problem. As it stands your code is running O(n^2). If you are wanting to improve your runtime complexity then look into using a hash-table or a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to get the first number in an array that occurs twice, you can create a map of numbers and their counts, interrupting the execution flow when you have a count of 2.

Something like

```
public Integer search(int[] array) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    for (int a : array) {
        int count = counts.getOrDefault(a, 0);
        count++;
        if (count == 2) {
            return a;
        }
        counts.put(a, count);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't catch the purpose of your method.

But if you are trying to find an index of an element from an array

try something like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(new int[] {1 ,  2, 3}, 3));
```

Also, if it's the case, searching for what key in "`public static Integer search(int array[])`" you are trying? Search method name suggests also a key as an argument.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24982857)

Comment: ok, i got it. In 3 days here i a´m just testing and understanding the dinamic of this platform. Thank for help

Comment: We have all been there. Thanks for the attempt and sticking with it. :-)